# Mixed Solvent MD using OpenMM

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-mechanics, graphical-processing-unit

I switched to using OpenMM recently and have got up and running without too much of a learning curve.

My general workflow is as follows, using a cloud based GPU to actually run the simulation:

1. Prepare the protein (cap, fill missing loops etc)
2. Set up the system (fill box with water, neutralise and add ‘salt’)
3. Run MD

If the protein has a ligand, it’s straightforward to parametrise and generate a forcefield for this.

What I’m unable to find info about is running a mixed solvent /cryptic pocket type experiment (where for example there is a certain % of a probe such as benzene).  In other tools I’ve used previously there are functions to do this and randomly place the probe similar to how ions are placed,  but I find no info about this in the OpenMM documentation.

Adding x molecules of probe psuedo- randomly does not seem prudent

Comment: +1 and welcome to the site! After so many years on Chem.SE you finally made an account here :) Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to run a mixed solvent experiment in Openmm? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Can you try creating two layers of the molecules: let's say water and benzene and run a short equilibration run so that they mix with each other?